# Is "there" a subject?

Tags: pronouns, linking-verbs, subject-complement

A clause usually has a subject and a verb. For example, in this sentence,

> "Joe loves baseball".

"Joe" is the subject, "loves" is the verb.

How about "there is"?

> There's someone on the phone for you.

Is "there" the subject here? If yes, is "there" a noun or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sentence, "there" is a dummy pronoun used as the subject of the sentence. It has no meaning in itself. See this link:

[Thoughtco "Existential Sentence"](https://www.thoughtco.com/existential-sentence-grammar-1690689)